# Hash complications on authorizing

Tags: hashcode

I'm having this issue where the registration of an user is working, but then when I want to log in, and compare the hash I have on my DB with a generated hash (same function) I get dif hashs.

This is the code I'm using to hash stuff:

```
public function encryptPassword($password){
    return base64_encode(Pbkdf2::calc('sha256', $password, $this->salt, 10000, strlen($password*2)));
}
```

I use it on my setter:

```
public function setPassword($password) {
    $this->password = $this->encryptPassword($password);
    return $this;
}
```

And the problem I'm gettin is on my Repository, where I gerenate the hash again:

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository{

    public function findByEmailAndPassword($email, $password){
        $user = $this->findOneByEmail($email);

        if($user){
            $hashSenha = $user->encryptPassword($password);
            if($hashSenha == $user->getPassword()){
                return $user;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I get a slightly different hascode from what I meant to get, as you can see here:

[image]

What may be causing that ?

Thanks in advance,
Danilo Scanferla